# How to make a text input align to center, but have the cursor aligned left when focused?

Tags: html, css

I have an input text like the following:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" style="text-align:center"/>
```

The placeholder is correctly shown centered, but when I focus on the field, the cursor is also at the center of the text field, and I want it to be at the left of the placeholder.
How can I align the cursor only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) selector.

You probably also want to use [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) selector so that the placeholder doesn't move.

```css
input, input::placeholder {
    text-align: center; 
}

input:focus {
    text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
```

Comment: Unusual requirement, brilliant answer.

Comment: You don't need to select both input and placeholder, because then when you lose focus it goes back to the center, not sure if that is desirable

Comment: @ZohirSalak - Yeah, I'm not sure either. Maybe only the placeholder should be centered.

Comment: In that case the Op can select only the place holder

Comment: Didn't work for me i needed to cursor when focus on left but text should remain in center. They he jerk is not desireable